# Set search path in postgresql in a spring boot application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

How to set search path in postgresql to switch to new schema based on tenant id ?
I want to resolve the tenant at runtime and redirect the request to specific schema.
The application I am developing is a spring boot application with Data JPA.

Refer [here](https://hackernoon.com/your-guide-to-schema-based-multi-tenant-systems-and-postgresql-implementation-gm433589) to perform multitenancy in postgresql using set search path.

Comment: You can 1) Set it as a parameter of the spring boot app, or 2) Change the search path for the user. I prefer to do #2 every time. It's just safer.

Comment: Search_path is a postgresql env variable . Can you please mention how to set it dynamically and what is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. There is an option to set the search_path:

In flyway during migration it can be done using :

```
Flyway fly = Flyway.configure()
                    .dataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/multitenancy_schema", "postgres", "operator")
                    .schemas(tenant)    // Setting the schema before creating migrating/making changes to DB.                                      
                    .load();
             fly.migrate();
```